# Why are Strom-Hurewicz-cofibrations necessarily closed?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cofibrations

We consider the category $\mathsf{CG}$ of [compactly generated spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+generated+topological+space) (since the question becomes obsolete for compactly generated weakly hausdorff spaces). A [Hurewicz-fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hurewicz+fibration) is a map with the *homotopy lifting property*. A [Hurewicz-cofibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hurewicz+cofibration) is a map with the *homotopy extension property*. We will call a map with the LLP against trivial Hurewicz-fibrations a *Strom-Hurewicz-cofibration*, since they are the cofibrations in the [Strom model structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Str%C3%B8m+model+structure).

> Is there an immediate argument, why Strom-Hurewicz-cofibrations are closed maps? Or even better, why they are precisely the closed Hurewicz cofibrations?

Of cause we can invoke the recognition principle, saying that Strom-Hurewicz-cofibrations are precisely the [NDR-pairs](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/neighborhood+retract), but this result requires quite some work. I was wondering, whether there is a more direct argument (at least for the "necessarily closed" part) along the following lines:

An inclusion $f:A \rightarrow B$ is closed, if and only if the lifting problem
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
   A & \xrightarrow{\Bbb 1_A} & \{0,1\}_S\\
{\small f}\downarrow && \downarrow\\
B & \xrightarrow{\Bbb 1_{f(A)}} & \{0,1\}_C
\end{array}$$
admits a solution, where $\{0,1\}_S$ denotes the Sierpinski space with $\{1\}$ closed, $\{0,1\}_C$ is equipped with the chaotic/indiscrete topology, the horizontal maps are characteristic/indicating functions and the underlying function of the right map is the identity. It is a fun exercise to show that $\{0,1\}_S$ and $\{0,1\}_C$ are contractible and that the right map constitutes a homotopy equivalence. But unfortunately it is not a Hurewicz-fibration, since lifting properties of the form
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
   * & \rightarrow & \{0,1\}_S\\
{\small in_0}\downarrow\,\; && \downarrow\\
[0,1] & \rightarrow & \{0,1\}_C
\end{array}$$
need not admit a solution. Moreover I don't know (or rather missed to check) wether the spaces $\{0,1\}_S$ and $\{0,1\}_C$ are actually compactly generated. Anyway I think this would have been a very neat argument to see the necessity of Strom-Hurewicz-cofibrations being closed. In other words

> Can we use a lifting problem against a trivial Hurewicz-cofibration to show that maps with LLP against trivial Hurewicz-fibrations are closed?

Thank you for your time and considerations!

Comment: The Strom cofibrations in $Top$ are regular monos. The same is true in weak Hausdorff (and hence in Hausdorff) spaces, where the regular monos are closed embeddings.

Comment: Thank you. I know that cofibrations are inclusions of subspaces (ie regular monos). My real question is, why in the Strom model structure on $\mathsf{CG}$ (**not** $\mathsf{CGWH}$) the cofibrations need to be closed (ie why plain Hurewicz cofibrations don’t suffice). In the case of weakly hausdorff they just are, but in $\mathsf{CG}$ there is this discrepancy. This is what this question is about, preferably without using NDR-pairs…

Comment: Look at the proof of Theorem 9 in A. Strom's paper 'Note on Cofibrations II'.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Unfortunately from this proof it is not obvious, why we need closed cofibrations. It comes into play, when he invokes theorem 4 of *Notes on Cofibrations I*, which then uses the characterization in terms of NDR-pairs (which are in particular closed). My question is, whether closedness is a formal consequence of having the lifting property against trivial fibrations, ie. if there is a simple lifting problem with the right map being a trivial fibration, which a cofibration can solve only if it is closed...

Comment: It is. I have some notes called 'Fibrations II' (see Theorem 6.2) which you can track down if you want to see the trick (which is taken almost verbatim from Strom's papers and doesn't use NDR pairs). Btw, Strom's definitions in 'Note on Cofibrations' yield cofibrations which need not be closed.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is precisely what I was looking for. If you want to, you can write this as an answer, so we can close this question. I really appreciate your notes btw!